# Views path registry problem

Tags: views, uri

I am getting trouble with views path registering.. So, I created custom entity message system (mimic of PrivateMessage module) which allows users write messages to another users (it also allows anonymous users to write messages by multiple checks).. I then wanted to show users listing of their messages by user id.. Created a view, within views UI everything works fine (view has been saved also):
[image]

[image]

But I can not access the page by URL which views supplied:
[image]

I can register it manually by hook_menu, but it is interesting why path is not being registered automatically.

Comment: How is your contextual filter configured to handle the case when no value is passed in?  What happens if you go to the url myMessages/4

Comment: Type: Raw value from URl. Path component: 2 (this is user id)

Comment: But the path myMessages does not have a path component 2.
If you make it something like user/%/myMessages and have it show as a tab in the user account area then the uid would be in there and available to your contextual filter.

Comment: You are right absolutely.. looks like I am tired a little bit)) I should configure Contextual Filter by PHP code rather then raw value (i just want to get URL like messages or something shorter, not like user/%/something) thanks a lot))